# Moving opened google map infoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude, infowindow

I create google map infoWindow in this way

```
newMapView.infowindow.setContent(contentString);
newMapView.infowindow.setPosition(catMarker.getPosition());
newMapView.infowindow.open(newMapView.map);
```

But need to move map center little up. Tryed to do something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var point = map.getCenter();
    point.Xa = point.Xa+1/1000;
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(point.Xa,point.Ya));
},1000);
```

*Need timeout to know what window already oppenen and moved to center.*

But this method work not properly in some cases, and using timeout is not good solution as I understood.

Is there any way to put marken in one place but move center to other?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use [google.maps.Map.setCenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) to set the center of the map to start with? Does opening the infowindow cause the map to move? You haven't provided your initialization code, that would be the correct place to do it.  Also the ".Xa" is not a documented property of a LatLng object it can (and does) change with every release.

Comment: I'm using `setCenter` but it works not properly, because automatic map move on infowindow open takes some time. I need catch "onopen" event, but can't.